# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Orders::BuildController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Working with these models:

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :quotes
end
```

Quote.rb

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :country_quotes, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :countries, through: :country_quotes, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

Country.rb

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :country_quotes, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :quotes, through: :country_quotes, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

Country_Quote.rb

```
class CountryQuote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country, dependent: :delete
  belongs_to :quote, dependent: :delete
end
```

Via console, I can run this query and I get the result I'm looking for:

```
theresults = Quote.joins(:countries).where("countries.name = 'España'")
theresults.where(shippingtype: 'Urgente').first.cost
```

However when I try to run a similar query within build_controller.rb (it's a controller to handle my Wicked gem for the model Order) I get this error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Orders::BuildController#update
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "order" LINE 1: ...RE "quotes"."user_id" = $1 AND (countries.name = @order.coun... ^

```
class Orders::BuildController < ApplicationController
  
    def update
    
      temporderregularshippingprice = @user.quotes.joins(:countries).where("countries.name = @order.country" )
      puts 'user.quotes2: ' + @user.quotes
      puts 'order.country2: ' + @order.country
      orderregularshippingprice = temporderregularshippingprice.where(shippingtype: 'Ordinario').first.cost # line returning the error
      puts 'orderregularshippingprice: ' + orderregularshippingprice.to_s

    ...

    end

end
```

According to the trace, @user.quotes and @order.country are correctly detected from that part of the code:

```
11:04:21 web.1    |   ↳ app/controllers/orders/build_controller.rb:52:in `update'
11:04:21 web.1    | orderpriceperpage: 
11:04:21 web.1    | **user.quotes2**: #<Quote::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000001132da8c0>
11:04:21 web.1    | **order.country2**: España
11:04:21 web.1    |   Quote Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "quotes".* FROM "quotes" INNER JOIN "country_quotes" ON "country_quotes"."quote_id" = "quotes"."id" INNER JOIN "countries" ON "countries"."id" = "country_quotes"."country_id" WHERE "quotes"."user_id" = $1 AND (countries.name = @order.country) AND "quotes"."shippingtype" = $2 ORDER BY "quotes"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 2], ["shippingtype", "Ordinario"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
11:04:21 web.1    |   ↳ app/controllers/orders/build_controller.rb:62:in `update'
11:04:21 web.1    | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms (ActiveRecord: 13.8ms | Allocations: 22630)
11:04:21 web.1    | 
11:04:21 web.1    | 
11:04:21 web.1    |   
11:04:21 web.1    | ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "order"
11:04:21 web.1    | LINE 1: ...RE "quotes"."user_id" = $1 AND (countries.name = @order.coun...
11:04:21 web.1    |                                                              ^
11:04:21 web.1    | ):
11:04:21 web.1    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the variable in double quotes which is interpreted as string.

```
temporderregularshippingprice = @user.quotes.joins(:countries).where("countries.name = @order.country" )
```

Use this instead

```
temporderregularshippingprice = @user.quotes.joins(:countries).where("countries.name = ?", @order.country )
```

OR

```
temporderregularshippingprice = @user.quotes.joins(:countries).where(countries: { name: @order.country })
```